# Having arbitrary number of arguments with a named default in python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I want to write a function in python that can take an arbitrary number of unnamed arguments in addition to one named argument (with a default).

For example, I want to write something like this

```
def myFunc(*args, optDefault=1):
```

But this just gives a syntax error. Is there an equivalent way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
def myFunc(*args, **kwargs):
    optDefault = kwargs.pop('optDefault', 1)
    assert kwargs == {}, "There may only be one keyword argument to myFunc"
```

Not the prettiest, but it works.

Comment: assert not(kwargs) is a better idiom ;)

Comment: GaretJax: I suppose that's a matter of taste :-) Not as a function? Yuck!

Comment: Things like that should result in a `TypeError`, not in an `AssertionError`. And yes, `not kwargs` is more idiomatic (although polymorphism doesn't matter here much, it's a pretty save bet to assume `type(kwarg) is dict`).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
def myFunc(optDefault=1, *args):
```

Comment: Thanks! But I dont know how to call it. myFunc(optDefault=3,1,2) and myFunc(1,2,optDefault=3) both give errors.

Comment: @highBandWidth how about myFunc(3,1,2)?

Comment: @Shaokan: your suggestion would defeat the point (whatever that may be for highBandWidth) of having a keyword args...

Answer (score -2):

why dont you use [this](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), 
an example (I borrow from [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/OptParse))

```
import optparse

if __name__=="__main__":
    parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage: %prog [options] arg1 arg2")
    parser.add_option("-H", "--host", dest="hostname",
                      default="127.0.0.1", type="string",
                      help="specify hostname to run on")
    parser.add_option("-p", "--port", dest="portnum", default=80,
                      type="int", help="port number to run on")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) != 2:
        parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")
    hostname = options.hostname
    portnum = options.portnum
```

Comment: optparse [is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) and it was intended for another usage (parse command line options).