# How to create a function with both default and arbitrary arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm trying to write a function that will contain some default values, with the possibility of having some additional parameters sent in.  For example, I would like something along the lines of this:

```
def defaultsAndArbitrary(arr, example1=True, example2=13, *modifiers):
    #code
```

Then, I'd like to be able to call the function like so:

```
defaultsAndArbitrary([1,5,3,9], modifier1, modifier2)
```

With that call, the values for the arguments should be:

```
arr = [1,5,3,9]
example1 = True
example2 = 13
modifiers = (modifier1, modifier2)
```

There's a similar question here:

[Having arbitrary number of arguments with a named default in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902192/having-arbitrary-number-of-arguments-with-a-named-default-in-python)

But it doesn't really answer this question (at least, to my understanding).  Is it even possible to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def defaultsAndArbitrary(arr, *modifiers, **kwargs):
    example1 = kwargs.get('example1',True)
    example2 = kwargs.get('example2',13)
```

Comment: I typed this in, and when I sent in example1 = False, it properly changed it to False.  Why is that, though?  To me, example1 = kwargs.get('example1', True) is setting the value of example 1 AFTER the arguments are read in, thus overwriting the argument?

Comment: `kwargs.get('example1', True)` is the same as `if 'example1' in kwargs: example1=kwargs['example1']; else: example1=True`. At the time this expression is evaluated, `kwargs` is already set through the function call.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can use [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).  That would look something like this:

```
def defaultsAndArbitrary(arr, *modifiers, example1=True, example2=13):
```

In Python 2 you must a use a solution like that given in the question you linked to: you must use `**kwargs` and manually extract `example1` and `example2` from the kwargs dict, supplying defaults if those kwargs are not passed.  This means that you can't specify their names or defaults in the function signature; you have to do it in the code of the function.

Note that in either case, your `example1` and `example2` variables *must* be passed by keyword (if you want to pass values for them instead of using the defaults); they cannot be passed positionally.

Comment: Ok, well I'm using Python 2.7 so I guess I can't do the first method :/ So in the second case, how do you declare a default without it overwriting the argument sent in?

Comment: @user2869231: The question that you linked to already shows how to do that (as does muraveil's answer).